# Events like SourceUpdated and TargetUpdated in WinUI 3

Tags: c#, events, textbox, winui-3

When using the [WPF TextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) I have the events `SourceUpdated` and `TargetUpdated`. Due to me using WinUI 3 I am using the following [WinUI TextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.textbox?view=winui-3.0) instead. Is there a similar way to get the same events?